# changing Direction in Globalization asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

**View**

```
   <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group" style="direction: rtl">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label class="control-label">@Resources.VMSResource.VisitorName </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VisitorName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm " } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VisitorName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label class="control-label">@Resources.VMSResource.EmployeeID </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

I am implementing globalization in MVC.

For the Arabic language, I want the controls direction to RTL. I tried setting the direction to RTL for the DIV:

```
 <div class="panel-body" style="direction:RTL">
```

But it is only setting the direction within the textbox to RTL. Instead I want the controls (like Label, textbox) to move RTL.

Comment: I guess you need to create a new css file that handles the direction of your div and place it in the `App_theme` folder and switch the default theme when changing the language

Comment: hmm.. I think the globalization should handle that. Is that right?

Comment: Globalization is the process of designing the application in such a way that it can be used by users from across the globe (multiple cultures).`http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati` 
it change only the language not the css as i know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a CSS that is designed for Left-To-Right languages to work with  Right-To-Left ones is not as easy as it seems. Just changing a parent element's direction to RTL does not mean that all children become RTL correctly. There are more to do. For example, you should change margin-right to margin-right or change the padding's values, etc.

In this way there are several tutorials that are based on different methods; all of them have pros and cons. To start I recommend you [3 Different Ways to RTL your CSS](http://www.rtl-this.com/tutorial/3-different-ways-rtl-your-css) and [RTLCSS](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss)

If you are using Bootstrap, the best choice, in my opinion, is https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. May Allah Bless you and admit you in Paradise.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html dir="@(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft? "rtl" : "ltr")">
```

Code sample taken from aspnet core

In detail, you can reach from the link below.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp

Answer (score 0):

In Html use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
...
```

this change almost everything to right for me except the labels so used this in my site.css file

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    float: right;
}
```